# How can I change the ids of my cloned dropdown list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I have the following Drop Down List in php:

```
<select id="choice" name="choice" style="width: 121px">
    <?php 
    foreach($xml->children() as $pizza){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $pizza; ?>" selected=""><?php echo $pizza; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select><input TYPE = "button" id="addbt" Name = "addbt" VALUE = "Add Pizza">
```

and I am using the following Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#addbt").click(function () {
     $('#choice').clone().insertAfter("#choice");
  });

</script>
```

I am trying to clone the Drop Down List which is attached to an xml file (I managed till here) and add the Jquery necessary so each new drop down list clone has a new id (a single number difference would be enough. Something like choices_00 then choices_01 and so on).

Since I am totally new to Jquery and php I am asking for any advice or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after this: http://jsfiddle.net/ehQan/

```
$("#addbt").click(function () {
    $('#choice').clone().attr( 'id', 'choices_' +$(this).index()).insertAfter("#choice");
});
```

Comment: `$(this).index()` is not a good solution. What if more elements are added to the same parent?

Answer (score 4):

```
 $("#addbt").click(function () {
     $('#choice').clone()
         .attr('id', 'newid')
         .attr('name', 'newname')
         .insertAfter("#choice");
  });
```

To ensure you get a new name and id each time, consider adding a class name to the select so you can count how many exist.

HTML:

```
<select id="choice" name="choice" class="ddl" style="width: 121px">
    <?php 
    foreach($xml->children() as $pizza){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $pizza; ?>" selected=""><?php echo $pizza; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

JS:

```
 $("#addbt").click(function () {
     $('#choice').clone()
         .attr('id', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
         .attr('name', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
         .insertAfter(".ddl:last");
  });
```

Otherwise, track how many times the button has been clicked with a global variable (ugh) or data attribute.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't change the name on all the new ones. I need that if i click the add button 10 times there will be 11 different IDs (the 10 new ones plus the original).

Comment: Awesome :). Thanks so much. I have been trying to solve this today and yesterday and I just ended up desperate. luckily I found stackoverflown. Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanMarkCamilleri Pleasure, and welcome to SO. Don't forget to upvote and mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the id using the jQuery `attr()` method before you insert it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#addbt").click(function () {
        $('#choice').clone().attr('id','Your new id').insertAfter("#choice");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Yes but it doesn't change the name on all the new ones. I need that if i click the add button 10 times there will be 11 different IDs (the 10 new ones plus the original).

Comment: @Jai: I think we typed it up at the same time and I just took longer. It looks like the question has been answered now.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can push the button as many times as you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var times = 0;
  $("#addbt").click(function () {
    times++;
    $('#choice').clone().attr( 'id', 'choices_' + times ).insertAfter("#choice");
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks :) already looking better. Is there a way to know the numbers though? like #Choices_00,#Choices_01,#Choices_02 and so on ?

Comment: You can declare a variable: `var times = 0;` then use instead of the Date part. Don't forget to increase the value of the variable in the click event also.

Comment: It is: `$('#choice').clone().attr( 'id', 'choices_' + times).insertAfter("#choice");`. I don't recommend using global variables but it will do the trick.

Comment: @Jai answer is much better, look at it.